# Create view layer in ArcGIS Online with some specific fields from source layer using ArcGIS API

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I want to create a view layer in ArcGIS Online with some specific fields from a source layer.

I used the following code

```
import arcgis
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayerCollection

user_name = "UserName"
pass_word = "PassWord"
gis = arcgis.gis.GIS("https://www.arcgis.com", user_name, pass_word)
layer_name = "My_layer"
view_name = "My_view1"
layer_index = 0
view_def = {"viewDefinitionQuery": "Fields in ['ch_name']"}

search_results = gis.content.search(layer_name, item_type="Feature Layer")
proper_index = [index for index, s in enumerate(search_results)
if '"' + layer_name + '"' in str(s)]
found_item = search_results[proper_index[0]]
flc = FeatureLayerCollection.fromitem(found_item)
new_view = flc.manager.create_view(name=view_name)
view_flc = flc
view_layer = view_flc.layers[layer_index]
flc.manager.update_definition(view_def)
```

The code shows an error for the following line:

```
"view_def = {"viewDefinitionQuery": "Fields in ['ch_name']"}"
```

Please help me write the view definition correctly to display only selected fields.